# How to hide/remove default Submit button generated in json schema form Angular 2

Tags: html, json, angular, typescript, schema

[Image of Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKBr4.png) (The update and cancel are correct the submit button is not wanted)
I'm trying to generate a json schema form without the default Submit button being generated. The button is not referenced in the schema or the html but its still generated. The closest I've got is using "options": false in the schema which causes an error which temporarily removes the button.
Does anyone know how to solve this?

```
{
  "type": "object", 
  "required": [
    "apiName",
    "targetHost",
    "targetPort",
    "numIterations",
    "concurrentUsers",
    "allowablePeakMemoryVariance",
    "allowableServiceResponseTimeVariance",
    "testSuite",
    "requestDelay",
    "TPSFreq",
    "rampUsers",
    "rampDelay",
    "testCaseDir",
    "testSuiteDir",
    "baseStatsOutputDir",
    "reportOutputDir"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "hiddenInput": {
      "type": "boolean",
      "widget": "hidden",
      "default": false,
      "addSubmit": false
    },

    "apiName": { "type": "string" },
    "targetHost": { "type": "string" },
    "targetPort": {
      "type": "string",
      "minimum": 1,
      "maximum": 65535
    },
    "memoryEndpoint": { "type": "string" },
    "numIterations": { "type": "integer", "minimum": 1 },
    "concurrentUsers": { "type": "integer", "minimum": 1 },
    "allowablePeakMemoryVariance": {
      "type": "number",
      "minimum": 0,
      "maximum": 100
    },
    "allowableServiceResponseTimeVariance": {
      "type": "number",
      "minimum": 0,
      "maximum": 100
    },
    "testSuite": {
      "type": "string",
      "enum": ["Default-1", "Default-2", "Default-3"]
    },
    "requestDelay": { "type": "integer", "minimum": 1 },
    "TPSFreq": { "type": "integer", "minimum": 1 },
    "rampUsers": { "type": "integer", "minimum": 1 },
    "rampDelay": { "type": "integer", "minimum": 0 },
    "testCaseDir": { "type": "string" },
    "testSuiteDir": { "type": "string" },
    "baseStatsOutputDir": { "type": "string" },
    "reportOutputDir": { "type": "string" }    
  },
  "layout" : [
    {
      "type": "flex",
      "flex-flow": "row wrap",
      "items": [
        "apiName",
        "numIterations",
        {
          "key": "requestDelay",
          "title": "Request Delay (ms)"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "flex",
      "flex-flow": "row wrap",
      "items": [
        "targetHost",
        "concurrentUsers",
        {
          "key": "TPSFreq",
          "title": "TPS Frequency (s)"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "flex",
      "flex-flow": "row wrap",
      "items": [
        "targetPort",
        {
          "key": "allowablePeakMemoryVariance",
          "title": "Memory Variance (%)"
        },
        "rampUsers"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "flex",
      "flex-flow": "row wrap",
      "items": [
        "memoryEndpoint",
        {
          "key": "allowableServiceResponseTimeVariance",
          "title": "Service Variance (%)"
        },
        {
          "key": "rampDelay",
          "title": "Ramp Delay (s)"
        }
      ]
    },
    { "key": "testSuite" },
    { "key": "testCaseDir", "title": "Test Case Directory" },
    { "key": "testSuiteDir", "title": "Test Suites Directory" },
    { "key": "baseStatsOutputDir", "title": "Base Stats Output Directory" },
    { "key": "reportOutputDir", "title": "Report Output Directory" }


  ]
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class=" column  col-md-8">
            <label>Config File Path *</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="string" [(ngModel)]="configPath" id="config-file-path" required>

        </div>
        <div class=" column col-md-4">
            <label>File Select</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="xml-file-name" placeholder="Click to Browse Files" [(ngModel)]="xmlFileName" type="string" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('file').click();">
            <input id="file" type="file" (change)="fileSelector($event)" />

        </div>


    </div>
    <json-schema-form name="auto-generated-fields" ngDefaultControl [schema]="configSchema" ngModel="formData" [layout]="configSchema.layout" framework="bootstrap-4">
    </json-schema-form>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="update-config-file-btn" *ngIf="xmlFileName && configPath" (click)="onUpdate(formData)">Update</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="cancel-btn" (click)="onCancel()">Cancel</button>

</div>
```

Comment: It depends on input types for both the variable.. If both the variable(configPath && file) is filled with values, button will be enabled.

Comment: The update button isnt the issue, its a submit button that is auto generated by the json schema form which is causing the problem

Comment: check this out [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-json-schema-form)  it gives you complete insight how this node module has been used.

Comment: Thanks, I've been looking at this page for some time and can't seem to pinpoint exactly where the submit button generation is occurring.

Comment: Cool..Upvote the suggestion so that others also can get benefit of it..Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I still having the same problem

Comment: You can override the widget that is used to display the submit button by mapping it to the "NoneComponent", which will cause the form to not render any button with the form.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to prevent submit button from rendering you can override the default submit button widget. Angular2 Schema Form includes a `NoneCompnent` that can serve a no-op drop in replacement for anything you don't want to display.

your.component.html :

```
<json-schema-form
[schema]="yourJsonSchema"
[layout]="yourJsonFormLayout"
[(data)]="yourData"
[widgets]="yourWidgets"
...
>
</json-schema-form>
```

your.component.ts :

```
...

import { NoneComponent } from 'angular2-json-schema-form';

...

@Component({
  selector: 'app-your-component',
  templateUrl: './your.component.html',
  ...
})
export class YourComponent {

  yourWidgets = {
    submit: NoneComponent,  
  }

...
```

Comment: is there any want to change the value of submit button .?

Comment: you could provide a widget implementation that overrides the submit button or you could hide the submit and provide your own control outside the form that triggers form submission.

Comment: Yes, i kept outside the form, but just want to know how to change submit button text.

Comment: I haven't used that framework in about a year, but if memory serves providing a widget that wraps or inherits the default submit button should do it, if there isn't a simple api provided for setting the submit text directly.